# How to drop NaN values from a dataset without removing entire rows?

Tags: python, database, pandas, nan

I'm dealing with a dataset that has a lot of NaN values, [as displayed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzVTV.png)

However, when I try to drop the NaN values, it compresses the entire dataset into absolutely nothing, [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbtDM.png)

Is there anyway I can remove the NaN values without jeopardizing the entire dataset?

Comment: What is your expected output? Replace NaN with blank string? In most probability, if you do that, your data will be of little use.

Comment: Think about what you want to do. If you have a two-dimensional table, you can't "remove" cells that contain NaN and leave a gap in the table - you have to remove the column or row they're in. NaN is the way you indicate that the value is missing.

Comment: There is possible remove rows with all `NaN`s or create `tuples` or `list` with all data without `NaN` in one column - but then working with data is not easy.

Comment: You can replace the `NaN` values with some approximated values, like `mean` or `median` of the row or column depending on your problem statement and dataset.

Comment: `df2 = df.stack()`

Comment: It is obvious that you get an empty data frame because each row respectively each column with any NaN value gets removed. Consequently there is nothing left. Remove the NaN value by other values as recommended by MrPyCharm and COLDSPEED